# Should I use prefix in public classes for my public frameworks in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style, shared-libraries, naming-conventions

**Should I use prefix in public classes for my public `Frameworks` in `Swift`?**

We are developing a framework in `Swift` which will be published for public use. My manager wants to keep no prefix for classes and suggested to use simpler names because of cleaner coding usually followed by Swift itself (unlike Objective-C). He suggested to name classes like,

```
class ConnectionManager {}
class BluetoothManager {}
class BluetoothDevice {}
```

I am feeling a different opinion because as the framework will be used by many 3rd party developers, they might face conflicts in their apps with their own classes (*as well as with some classes from other frameworks and iOS frameworks itself*) if we do not use a prefix. So, I suggested to use with our company suitable prefix like `'SA'`,

```
class SAConnectionManager {}
class SABluetoothManager {}
class SABluetoothDevice {}
```

Is it worth to avoid prefix for the sake of clean coding instead of using prefix for avoiding further conflicts for 3rd party developers?

**What are the possible problems I can face, if I avoid prefixing?**

Comment: Go on, it's good to have prefix to avoid conflicts with existing ones.

Comment: But the linked answer suggests not to use any prefix.